# A Problem related to Composition of Functions

Tags: functions

The problem is

> *f(x) = 2x + a for x ≥ -1* and *bx<sup>2</sup> + 3 for x < -1*
>
> and
>
> *g(x) = x + 4 for 0 ≤ x ≤ 4* and *-3x - 2 for -2 < x < 0*
>
> The question is to calculate the ranges of *a* and *b* for which *g(f(x))* is not defined.

I tried this problem by calculating *g(f(x))*. Then I tried working with the domains and ranges but I could not get any answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming the question means find the range of values of $a$ and $b$ for which $g(f(x))$ is not defined for any values of $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

$g(x)$ is only defined in the range $-2 \lt x \le 4$. So we want to find the range of values of $a$ and $b$ for which $f(x)$ never takes values in the range $-2 \lt f(x) \le 4$. So for all values of $x$ we must have either $f(x) \le -2$ or $f(x) > 4$.

The best way to approach this is to break it down into cases:

For $x \ge -1$, $f(x) = 2x + a$ so $f(x) \ge a-2$. So $f(x) \gt 4$ for all $x \ge -1$ if and only if $a-2 \gt 4$ and so $a \gt 6$.

For $x < -1$ and $b \ge 0$ then $f(x) = bx^2+3 \ge b + 3$. So $f(x) \gt 4$ for all $x < -1$ if and only if $b+3 \gt 4$ and so $b \gt 1$.

To complete the solution you also need to consider the third case which is $x <-1$ and $b < 0$.